# Update multiple variables in an IF Statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am having some trouble updating multiple variables inside an IF Statement and not sure where i'm going wrong.

Here is my code:

```
$id = $_POST['retrive_quantity'];  
$n_quantity = $_POST['n_quantity'];


$result2 = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM stock_control WHERE id = '$id' ");

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
  $quantity=$row1['quantity'];
  $threshold=$row1['threshold'];
  $emailSent=$row1['email_sent'];
  $orders_status=$row1['orders_status'];
  $orders=$row1['orders'];
}

if ($quantity + $n_quantity > $threshold && $emailSent == 2) {
    $update=0 && $orders_status=0 && $orders=0;
 } else {
    $update=2 && $orders_status=1 && $orders=$orders;
}

mysql_query("UPDATE stock_control SET quantity=quantity + '$n_quantity', 
email_sent = '$update', orders_status = '$orders_status', orders = '$orders' 
WHERE id = '$id' ");
```

The first line of the IF Statement works and also with just one of the variables, but fails with multiple.

Comment: Why do you not write something like this? $update = $orders_status= $orders=0;

Comment: I would also recommend moving away from `mysql_` functions as these are deprecated in newer versions of PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not update variables like this you have to separate with `;`

```
if ($quantity + $n_quantity > $threshold && $emailSent == 2) {
    $update=0;
    $orders_status=0;
    $orders=0; // or $update = $orders_status = $orders=0;
 } else {
    $update=2; 
    $orders_status=1;
    //$orders=$orders; //no need for this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable before used in if block

```
$id = $_POST['retrive_quantity'];  
$n_quantity = $_POST['n_quantity'];
$update=2;
$orders_status=1;
$orders=0;
$result2 = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM stock_control WHERE id = '$id' ");

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
  $quantity=$row1['quantity'];
  $threshold=$row1['threshold'];
  $emailSent=$row1['email_sent'];
  $orders_status=$row1['orders_status'];
  $orders=$row1['orders'];
}

if ($quantity + $n_quantity > $threshold && $emailSent == 2) {
    $update=0;
    $orders_status=0;
    $orders=0;
 } else {
    $update=2; 
    $orders_status=1;
    $orders=$orders;
}

mysql_query("UPDATE stock_control SET quantity=quantity + '$n_quantity', 
email_sent = '$update', orders_status = '$orders_status', orders = '$orders' 
WHERE id = '$id' ");
```